# SQL: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a very long query, and I can't identify why it returns this error.

If I change, in the query, "COMPANY NAME" it works normally.

I know that the query is long, so it may be difficult to help.

Thanks.

I'm using MYSQL 5.7, then I can't use IN in WHERE clause.

Comment: I fear that the number of people on here who can be bothered to wade through that will be limited, but I guess you only need one.

Comment: Try running through chunks of the query if possible, e.g. make sure your sub-queries work as expected. This might help you narrow down where the issue is. I don't think anyone wants to debug for you, and that's not what this site is for.

Comment: Every subselect can only return one row, so `LIMIT` all subselects to 1 row and think also of an `ORDER  BY` for all subselects, because without a limit doesn't make sense

Comment: I appreciate all the answers.

I know that nobody should debug my code, I don't want anyone to do my job.

I just wanted to get a sense of where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `"DFAGRO SOLUÇÕES CONTÁBEIS, TECNOLOGIA E GESTÃO LTDA"` have more than one rows possibly in mdl_user table. Check the institution column.